# function with unknown parameter is not assignable to function with string parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am using typescript and I defined the following interface:

```
export interface BaseProtocol {
    [key: string]: (payload: unknown) => Promise<unknown>;
}
```

Now I'd like to define a protocol:

```
import { BaseProtocol } from './BaseProtocol';

export interface AppProtocol extends BaseProtocol {
    action(payload: string): Promise<string>;
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Property 'action' of type '(payload: string) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to string index type '(payload: unknown) => Promise<unknown>'.ts(2411)
```

I am not willing to use any because it hurt the type safety of the Protocol usage.
Any idea how I can settle this issue?

Comment: `type AppProtocol = {
    action(payload: string): Promise<string>;
} & BaseProtocol;`

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: That's a TS type system quirks, not sure if it's documented anywhere, but that's how it should be done.

Comment: But than this gives me an error: `const a:Protocol = {
    action(payload: string){ return new Promise<string>((resolve)=>resolve() );
};`: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Oh, that's a surprise then, it should work. Let's see..

Answer (score 3):

The error is a valid one; if you have interfaces `A` and `B extends A`, then that if I want an `A` it's okay for you to hand me a `B`.  But with your definitions, that breaks:

```
function callBaseProtocol(bp: BaseProtocol) {
    return bp.action(12345);
}

function callAppProtocol(ap: AppProtocol) {
    callBaseProtocol(ap); // oops!
}
```

The function `callBaseProtocol()` is not in error.  The definition of `BaseProtocol` says that *every* string-valued key is a function which takes a value of type `unknown` and returns a `Promise<unknown>`.  Specifically, the `action` property of a `BaseProtocol` must be a function that accepts a value of type `unknown`.  You can therefore pass it a `number`.

The function `callAppProtocol()` is also not in error.  Here we are calling `callBaseProtocol()` and passing it an `AppProtocol`.  That is supposed to be acceptable because `AppProtocol extends BaseProtocol`.

But if an `AppProtocol` has an `action` property that expects a `string` and calls some `string`-specific method on it like `x => x.toUpperCase()`, this will explode.  The error is that `AppProtocol` does not, in fact, properly extend `BaseProtocol`.

---

This possibly surprising phenomenon is known as [parameter contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_parameter_type), where if `X` is a subtype of `Y`, then the function `(y: Y)=>any` is a subtype of `(x: X)=>any`, *and not vice versa*.  The direction of subtyping goes the other way for function parameters, and that "goes the other way" is what "contravariance" means.

This behavior was introduced in TypeScript via the [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types), and is a type safety improvement.

---

So how can you deal with this?  Assuming you want increased type safety and not reduced type safety (you mention not wanting to use `any`), then perhaps your `BaseProtocol` isn't really properly defined.  Maybe instead of having a string index signature and passing around `unknowns`, it should be a [generic](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) interface that represents a more complex relationship between input and output.  Perhaps something like this:

```
export type BaseProtocol<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (payload: T[K]) => Promise<T[K]>;
}
```

This is saying that a `BaseProtocol` depends on another type `T`, and that a `BaseProtocol<T>` has a method for every property of `T`, which takes a parameter of the type of that property value, and returns a `Promise` of that type.

And then `AppProtocol` can be simply defined as:

```
export interface AppProtocol extends BaseProtocol<{ action: string }> {
}
```

This solves the problem from before, since the compiler will not allow you to call a `BaseProtocol<T>`'s `action()` method on a `number` argument unless it knows that `T` has an `action` property of type `number`:

```
function callBaseProtocol<T>(bp: BaseProtocol<T>) {
    return bp.action(12345); // error! might not have an action
}
```

---

There's also a hybrid approach that doesn't assume the return value of each function is a promise of the same type as its input:

```
export type BaseProtocol<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (payload: T[K]) => unknown;
}

export interface AppProtocol extends BaseProtocol<{ action: string }> {
    action(x: string): Promise<string>;
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8BYAKDKUqQgA8YM0AXJAS2EYjQDMFkAhEFAjoMjDPAw4iFKrIDaAawgBPAFxIojNGwDmAXXUAKOMpwYQAE3UBXYAuAYA7sACUSALwA+VJjAshADy29k7AngDcMpQAvmRR1HQMzGwc3LxIAIIwMCJiElK0HMAWUEgCQrniktKksrIIjCwYwMYgpuZWGlq6LuoifoGa2sA6EfGx5LVUXLbwjc1I8CA4OOXCmHmShlgw6muV+W4kU3VIaBCM1mjASDsAdA1NLQCMAEwAzAAsAKwukSdICbxGbAOZPRbLHBZHIbKo4QwgXaZbIHSRHeKyJYrfaw-IImB-cZkIGkUCQWDpADiEGAnBY8Bqslo9CYSEYyhg-EE61EcICABVvO5GackHIANKsG5KZQYLhIfkGJCtdqWdT8iV6NxeHwYAYQAWasYAklMxKslKcHiIZEw3n5BJFEplbmonABQhIR7NdRDXSA7zHWSm6azeY3LGrV24yQCzzbJE4+2xwXogGyc6Xa63GAPMHNQxvL6-cJIAD0ZeoaEwaAAhEg-DoABbMBzMJsgABuyBAN29wCJk1kIPzEch0Ld+PUE5jODTooh2OjyfhiMJJoowLD4KwF1SAGFIUnNu7+QAaJCSwo050yuUK+MYqg7PbLk9xi8KdTii+d9Wa+J51FTMrhuHZFD0QxO3XYM4gBEdw1uPdOEPFYZxXKdbTdIDTl3RgDyPN84XxC8ACJ+1Ii8ix+P5y0rTga1rJ9KDwgilwqWcSKQcjR0o7iMAUNpSJgqgSWJOCyDJaA4BtAAZaAoGpWltAZIMqGZJI2Q5LkOJXOMPBFU4JSlJA73lRUjBMMw1QVTVtW8YIHGcf5YKHdTzWSdgrXSdCT0dG9SmPPlPX7X1uhGANDLqftDBoMLhh0XpdX1AI-RGY1XPEyYgA)

Comment: Thank you very much fo the explanation. Actually, the reason I need BaseProtocol at all, is that I have a `sendMssage<Protocol extends BaseProtocol>(name: keyof Protocol, payload: Parameters<keyof Protocol>[0])` method that uses Parameters<> and ReturnType<>. And BTW, return type is different than the payload which makes everything complex.