# How to use `unknown` in Typescript overloaded function implementation signature

Tags: typescript

What is wrong with this overload signature? My goal is to use overloaded signatures to create several type-safe versions of an permissively-typed API. The API takes a string `channel` parameter and a handler callback with an `event` first parameter and then whatever parameters you want `(event, ...args[]) => void`.

It seems to me that `string` can be assigned to `unknown`, so the overload argument `(event: Event, msg: string) => void` should work with the implementation argument `(event: Event, ...args: unknown[]) => void`

```js
function handle(
    channel: string,
    listener: (event: Event, ...args: any[]) => any
): void { }


export function typedIpcHandle( // ← Works great
    channel: "getVersion",
    listener: (event: Event) => string
): void;
export function typedIpcHandle( // ←  Error
    channel: "notifyUser",
    listener: (event: Event, msg: string) => void
): void;
export function typedIpcHandle(
    channel: string,
    listener: (
        event: Event, 
        ...args: unknown[] // ← any[] works, but unknown[] doesn't
    ) => unknown
): void {
    return handle(channel, listener);
}
```

The second overload signature gives this error: `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.(2394)`

This is IPC Handle in Electron, if that is helpful.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=17&pln=17&pc=1#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgBYEMIBMA2BTACmGROSgwgjxwC5kBnGAJzggHMAaY0nORvKkzoE8ANwEw6AUXEQYHZADpl6Jm3p1MATwDaAXQCUyALwA+ZNuAG6ohHCzIA3sgC+wd3gAeABwRMYyODQ8EjIMFreeFgAkt5QABKYuITcJOSYVLTIAERseDAAanhM9IgQ2VykyLz8gsJiEtKyMEZmDMysbFY2dlgA3MBevv6BkLBlYRFRsQlJ+ERV6ZTUdNkQCPAgWgCq9MUVqdV8MALF9c1NEgoAtvRsdIws7K3mtvbdyG-9gz5+AUHjULhSIxOKJbDzQ5LTIPDrsSo8Y6nITIBZVUgNOSXOQKQ5VZSKVTqOiQADW6wA7hB9IcXsgyZSIB8vk5Dkx8mAmCgKMkCNDqAoaidBAYBi4gA)

Comment: TS function arguments are`contravariant`, so although `string extends unknown`, it is not contravariant, thus it does not work.

Comment: Using `any` is explicitly acknowledging that you might do something unsafe, while using `unknown` is saying that you promise to be safe.  And what you're doing is not guaranteed to be safe. You shouldn't assign a value of type `(msg: string) => void` to a value of type `(...args: unknown[]) => void` because the former *requires* a `string` input and someone calling the latter is *not required* to supply one. Leading to possible runtime errors like [this](//tsplay.dev/w66EYw). I'd suggest doing something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP7bqm), or just stick with `any` instead of `unknown`.

Comment: Please review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58458982/2887218) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60766676/2887218) and their answers.  If you don't think this question is resolved by those answers, let me know.  Otherwise this might get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @jcalz The linked answers seem to explain the core issue—[function argument contravariance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance). My difficulty is specifically in the context of the implementation signature of an overloaded function. The implementation signature needs to be extremely widely typed, allowing for all possibilities in the overload signatures. Could you add an answer containing the information in your two TS playground links above, so that the effects of contravaiance in the implementation signature are addressed?